# hibernateTemplate and reading parent/Child classes into dataModel

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I have come unstuck with this goal after successfully using a dataModel when rendering the result from a hibernateTemplate().find
on another class where there isn't a many-to-one mapping to another class.

Has anyone used a similar definition like the one below where you need all of ParentClass plus just one property from the child class.
In my Use case I need to display the receiptDate alongside all the other values contained in the ParentClass instance.

```
<hibernate-mapping> <class catalog="myCatalog" name="myCatalog.model.orm.MyClass" table="myTable">
<id name="consignmentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
  <column name="myTable_id"/>
  <generator class="identity"/>
</id>
<many-to-one class="myCatalog.model.orm.ParentClass" fetch="select" name="pTable">
  <column name="pTable_id" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
<property name="receiptDate" type="timestamp">
  <column length="19" name="receipt_date" not-null="true"/>
</property> </class> </hibernate-mapping>
```

The nearest I have got is with:
hibernateTemplate().find("select c.parentClass from myClass c");

However when trying to adress the parentClass items e.g: parentClass.depotAddress
in the dataTable I get the following error as the parentClass has not been loaded:
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

I have just found a solution anyway, by forcing eager loading on the ParentClass via:

```
<many-to-one class="myCatalog.model.orm.ParentClass" lazy=false fetch="select" name="pTable">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is far from being clear. If what you want to do is load all the `MyClass` instances along with their `pTable` parent, the query to use is

```
select m from MyClass m inner join fetch m.pTable
```

This is of course described in the [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

Comment: First of all, let me make it clear that I did indeed check the docs.  I have tried to make the question as clear as possible by reducing the Use case to a simple one.  I prefer teh solution I have come up with in this particular case and thank all who have read this.